Не переведён новый комментарий о дубликате вопроса

Кроме того, комментарий похоже обрезался из-за того, что ссылка на вопрос оказалась слишком длинной и вылезла за лимит на длину комментария

edit t? Мне кажется, тут надо не переводить, а подождать, пока оригинал исправят, а то всё равно слетит.

Добавил переводы:

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/20530
https://ru.traducir.win/strings/20527

Будет в новых сборках, текущая 2024.6.28.11669
Однако, на MSE есть обсуждение по этому комментарию Is a new comment format for duplicate votes being tested?
Так что многое может измениться.
Про обрезание комментария в предыдущих редакциях, есть старый баг-репорт Обрезалась ссылка при закрытии вопроса как дубликата существующего

Всё равно ж edit t будут править на edit it и перевод слетит?

@Qwertiy там не edit t, а порезанное edit the question

@Qwertiy посмотри ссылки на традусир, там видно строки исходные.

Что-то запаздывает перевод https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1585899#comment2861508_1585899

@andreymal там PR с переводами теперь требует ручного аппрува, а значит всё затягивается на хз сколько

Прилетел-таки https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/14305#comment58978_14305
