Как так? Поставил минус за ответ, а этот минус прилетел мне в репутацию. Так стала работать репутация?
Как  так? Поставил минус за ответ, а этот минус прилетел мне в репутацию. Так стала работать репутация? Ставить отвечающим минусы себе дороже?

Да, раздачу минусов вы оплачиваете своим рейтингом

Да всего-то единичка, не дорого. )  Но всё-таки сдерживает от необдуманного минусования.

Знаете, читал в форумах SO такую мысль: "Человек ставший минус надеется, что автор либо исправит свой ответ, либо удалит и в конце концов ему вернется потерянная 1 репутация".

Так репутация всегда работала.

@Grundy дата регистрации кстати 2011 год, работала ли она так тогда?

@andreymal, да, за ответы всегда снималась репутация

@andreymal на ХэшКоде не помню, возможно и не было такого, но с 2015 на ruSO точно уже так было. На ruSO (за время его существования) всегда так работала репутация.
